# SELECT with default result for empty condition?

Tags: abap, is-empty, opensql, isnullorempty

I have a database table with following fields and values:

```
Bukrs | Werks | Btrtl | Persg | Persk | value
1000   1000     1001     1      20      1,20
1000                                    1,10
```

And I am building the query with the following key:

```
SELECT
FROM dbtab
INTO lv_value
WHERE bukrs = bukrs
    AND (
        werks = werks
        AND btrtl = btrtl
        AND persg = persg
        AND persk = persk
        )
```

So for query with the exact condition condition match the `value` must be 1,20, and that is correct.

But for another condition without full match e.g. `bukrs = 1000 werks = 1002 btrtl = 1003 persg = 2 persk = 27`, it must be 1,10.

So everything which doesn't fit full key should fallback to default line with value 1,10. For example:

Andrew has the following Parameters

```
Bukrs = 1000
Werks = 1000 
Btrtl = 1001
Persg = 1
Persk = 20
```

Peter has the following Parameters

```
Bukrs = 1000
Werks = 1004
Btrtl = 1002
Persg = 1
Persk = 27
```

For Andrew 1,20 should be selected, for Peter it should be 1,10.

Comment: Is `bukrs` a person identifier? What are you matching these values against? Is it always a single person at a time?

Comment: @shawnt00 yes it is everytime only one person. Yes Bukrs till persk is a person identifier, but Bukrs is filled everytime the others not. So Person 1 could have the values like the first entry and the value would be 1,20. Person 2 could have Bukrs 1000 but dont have the other parameters right, so the person should get the value 1,10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
DATA: Andrew TYPE dbtab.

Andrew-bukrs = '1000'.
Andrew-werks = '1000'.
Andrew-btrtl = '1001'.
Andrew-persg = '1'.
Andrew-persk = '20'.

SELECT SINGLE value INTO @DATA(Andy) 
  FROM dbtab WHERE werks = ANY ( SELECT CASE WHEN bukrs = @Andrew-bukrs 
                                              AND werks = @Andrew-werks 
                                              AND btrtl = @Andrew-btrtl
                                              AND persg = @Andrew-persg 
                                              AND persk = @Andrew-persk
                                        THEN werks 
                                        ELSE '9999' 
                                 END AS werks FROM dbtab 
                               ).

WRITE / Andy-value.
```

This snippet gives you 1.20, and the same query for the person with only BUKRS gives you 1.10.

```
DATA: Peter TYPE dbtab.

Peter-bukrs = '1000'.

SELECT ....
```

Explanation: here we simulate [XOR operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) for ABAP SQL through the subqueries. Our subquery always returns **two** values: only one truthful row from `dbtab` table, the other one is always a dummy 9999. This way the outer query will always return single value by the plant, either real or dummy.

Prerequisite for this solution: `9999` (subquery plant) must be invariably non-existent in `dbtab`.

Comment: Hey @Suncatcher thanks, like I said to "shawnt00" my system is unfortunaly not up to date. :) But I think your solution would work.

Comment: Another option is [to use UNION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58094183/911419) for your task, however if your system doesn't support CASE inside subqueries, unlikely it will support UNION (>750) as well :(

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it when the system will be updated. :)

Answer (score 0):

So I take it that you're matching against parameter values. Here's a shot in the dark as I don't know anything about ABAP.

```
SELECT
FROM dbtab
INTO lv_value
WHERE bukrs = bukrs
ORDER BY DECODE(
    (       werks = @werks
        AND btrtl = @btrtl
        AND persg = @persg
        AND persk = @persk
    ), 2,
    (werks IS NULL), 1
    0
)
UP TO 1 ROWS;
```

Comment: unfortunaly "CASE" is not allowed in ABAP. 
I tried "Select from dbtab into lv_value where bukrs = bukrs and werks = werks and btrtl = btrtl and persg = persg and persk = persk" but if one of these fields on the dbtab are empty then I dont get anything.

Comment: Looks like that might be a newer feature. Perhaps a `decode()`  will work then? And yes, that all have to match.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved my problem like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM  dbtab
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE LT_TAB
  WHERE  APPLICATION  = LV_APPL
  AND ( BUKRS = E_PERNR-BUKRS OR BUKRS IS NULL OR BUKRS = SPACE )
  AND ( WERKS = E_PERNR-WERKS OR WERKS IS NULL OR WERKS = SPACE )
  AND ( BTRTL = E_PERNR-BTRTL OR BTRTL IS NULL OR BTRTL = SPACE )
  AND ( PERSG = E_PERNR-PERSG OR PERSG IS NULL OR PERSG = SPACE )
  AND ( PERSK = E_PERNR-PERSK OR PERSK IS NULL OR PERSK = SPACE )
  AND    ENDDA       GE E_BEGDA
  AND    BEGDA       LE E_BEGDA
ORDER BY BUKRS DESCENDING WERKS DESCENDING BTRTL DESCENDING PERSG DESCENDING PERSK DESCENDING.

 READ TABLE LT_TAB INTO LS_TAB INDEX 1.
 LV_KWERT = LS_TAB-KONST.
```